# MySQL count time spent on site by user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+-----+---------+-------+------------+
|  Id |  UserId |  Page |  Timestamp |
+-----+---------+-------+------------+
```

And it contains a row for each page loaded by users:

```
+-------+--------+---------+--------------+
|     1 |  user1 |  page_x |  1393940340  |
|     2 |  user1 |  page_x |  1393940348  |
|     3 |  user1 |  page_x |  1393940390  |
|     4 |  user2 |  page_x |  1393940740  |
|     5 |  user2 |  page_x |  1393940781  |
|     6 |  user3 |  page_x |  1393910220  |
|     7 |  user1 |  page_x |  1393945555  |
|     8 |  user1 |  page_x |  1393945565  |
+-------+--------+---------+--------------+
```

I would like to calculate how much time each user has spent on the site.
As you can see for row 1, 2 and 3 (that were visited by user1) are easy to calculate as clearly the user spent 50 seconds but then on row 7 the same user returned to the site later on, if I keep counting as usual it will say that the user spent several hours or days as opposed to just 60 seconds.

Anyone has any idea on how to overcome this?

I though of maybe adding some limits, like if the time spent from one page to the other is over ~20 minutes then don't count it but I'm not sure how to add this to a MySQL query.

Comment: You have a lot to learn about sessionization and web site usage.  Your problem is more complicated than you think it is.  I would suggest that you start by doing research and read a book or two on the subject of web analytics.

Comment: You should define some threshold within which you'll count your time as belonging to one visit. It is not scalable solution and it has it's weakness, but at least it's a point to start from.

Comment: Your problem is conceptual and not a coding problem. You should define  how to calculate your times first before implementing anything. Or you could use http://piwik.org

Comment: "clearly the user spent 50 seconds" Really? While it's true that 90 - 40 = 50, why does it follow that that's how long the user spent on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,it can give you some clues to solve the problem:

```
SELECT USERID,SUM(RES) RESULT FROM
(SELECT T1.USERID,
CASE WHEN T1.USERID = T2.USERID THEN T2.TIMESTAMP - T1.TIMESTAMP ELSE 0 END RES
 FROM 
TABLE1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID - 1)TAB1
GROUP BY USERID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9dc96/16)

Comment: This is perfect! just 1 question, where can I add a clause to that query, if I wanted something like this: WHERE USERID != 'user10'?

Comment: You are welcome my friend.you can add where clause after `TAB1` like this:`TAB1 WHERE TAB1.USERID <> 'user10`